# What if a texture is bound to the context when attibute array of texture is off in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, shader, textures, bind

I have entities only with color so without texture and ones with texture. I don't want to get them mixed so I have two choice : using `glDisableVertexAttribArray(1)` and changing the fragment shader (In my shader location of texture is `1`, of vertex is `0`) or always keeping vertex and texture attribute arrays on and using a `1x1` white texture with `6` texture coordinates due to effect of not using `GL_TRIANGLES` instead of `GL_QUADS` on portability (white is in order to avoid deformation of the color given in multiplication operation. As you can guess my fragment shader looks like:

```
#version 330
layout(location=0)out vec4 color;
uniform vec4 _color;
uniform sampler2D tex;
in vec2 UV;
void main()
{
    color=vec4(texture(tex,UV).rgb,1)*_color;
}
```

I don't want to continuously turn on/off attribute arrays and don't want the latter too.
I has not used two certain way I found and tried the mixture of the two so used a `1x1` white pixel and turned on only vertex attribute array.

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); //for vertex
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1); //to turn off texture coordinates
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,...)
glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,...
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,flat) //flat is a 1x1 white texture so just a pixel
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,...);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Although I turn off texture attribute array, I get the result I want.Then, is there a guarantee for this code snippet to work everywhere?

The answer of this question is also a part of answer of the question of "What if a texture is bound to the context when attribute array of texture is off in `OpenGL`?"

Answer (score 4):

First things first, there's no "attribute array of texture"; you're completely mixing the terms, and I suggest you read up about them. What you have under index 1 is "arbitrary vertex attribute assigned by you to mean texture coordinates in your shaders".

I understand the problem you're having, and whilst it will work for now, it scales rather poorly. When you start introducing lighting and more complicated effects, you will end up in all kinds of unmaintainable mess.

Thus, my suggestion would be to set up a Program Pipeline instead of a Program and simply write two fragment shaders. As to disabling the Attribute Array, I think you're better off with enabling and disabling it (which you can do with a VAO) instead of putting **unnecessary overhead** on non-textured drawcalls.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English and lack of knowledge of OpenGL.I mean attribute array for texture and maybe this term is wrong too.
I couldn't understand how I will fail when I want to add lighting effect, etc.OK, I can directly change the fragment shader but I want to do without changing the situation of multiplication for using it to affect color of any object.
For the last one,
<br>
then, enabling and disabling is not a big overhead to worry about?

Comment: And yes, by using VAO I can avoid a substantial perfonmance penalty due to enable and disable functions.Thus, GPU knows how to treat the data according to VAO declared beforehand but I couldn't find answer to the 1x1 white pixel.Is there a way of doing the same without using texture and without changing the shader?

Comment: Not changing the shader is simply not worth it. And no, I wouldn't be so concerned about the cost of enabling and disabling the particular attribute.